# Extracting some part of a list

Tags: r, rna-seq, statistics

I have two normalized gene expression values (log2 of cpm)

```
> head(biomarker[,1:5])
               A2        A3        A4        A6        A7
A2M    12.4071618 12.631601 12.889748 11.842511 11.574134
ABCB11  0.5151957  6.176788  5.414905  7.134915  1.247590
ABCC2   6.7244303  6.487794 10.178615  6.384132  6.089462
ABCC6   6.3977122  5.823627  7.370761  7.397091  6.071587
ABCF1   9.1609847  9.893258 10.116638 10.225520 10.838486
ABCG2   7.6841874  7.738293  6.833152  6.888041  6.030032
>
```

And

```
> head(immune[,1:5])
              A2        A3        A4        A6        A7
A2M    10.904748 11.388404  9.910614 11.513439 12.963609
ABCB11  5.011380  6.359443  7.145992  8.451947  7.722605
ABCC2   5.040461  6.477014  3.873996  6.409777  9.133971
ABCC6   7.798441  7.601848  9.948072 11.628533 12.701460
ABCF1   8.553597  8.615425 11.145903 10.289098 11.444140
ABCG2   6.224294  5.629375  8.293416  7.979859  8.603793
> 

> dim(biomarker)
[1] 719  56
> dim(immune)
[1] 719  56
>
```

I have matched samples in these experiments and same gene too. I could roughly say in both experiments everything has been constant. However, I want to do Student's t-Test to find genes that they had inconsistent gene expression patterns between the two data sets.

By this function I am getting a list but I don't know how to extract the names of genes with p-value > 0.05 or whatever cut-off

```
> f <- function(x,y){
+     test <- t.test(x,y, paired=TRUE)
+     out <- data.frame(stat = test$statistic,
+                       df   = test$parameter,
+                       pval = test$p.value,
+                       conl = test$conf.int[1],
+                       conh = test$conf.int[2]
+     )
+     return(out)
+ }
> t=sapply(seq(ncol(t(biomarker))), function(x) f(t(biomarker)[,x], t(immune)[,x]))
```

Any help please?

```
  str(t)

    [list output truncated]
     - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 5 719
     - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
      ..$ : chr [1:5] "stat" "df" "pval" "conl" ...
  ..$ : NULL
    >


> sapply(t, "[[", "pval")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds
>  


> pvalueGenes <- sapply(colnames(biomarker),function(i) t.test(biomarker[i, ],immune[i, ], paired = TRUE)$p.value)
Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(x) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") :

 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) stop("data are essentially constant") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Did you try iterate by `colnames` instead? Have you searched the internet about how to get names of the variables you iterate over them? BTW you might be interested in the broom package, function `tidy`.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to do that

Comment: A simple google search would give you answers. You could use `tibble::rownames_to_column(biomarker, col_name)`. You could even do `biomarker$col_name <- colnames(biomarker)`

Comment: Sorry what is col_name please?

Comment: @FereshTeh you don't need to apologise for not knowing something. "col_name" is an abbreviation for column name. Use the help pages of those functions Ram mentioned to understand what do you need and what do they do

Comment: @FereshTeh Did you read and understood the help page of the `rownames_to_column` function?

Comment: Actually, no; You know, likely I have done t-test to find differentially expressed genes. I have 719 genes and two sets of samples while the function returns a list with 56 * 4 dimension that means t-test has been done between samples while I need to extract genes with p-value > 0.05 among two sets of datasets, that is why I got confused and I don't know rownames_to_colnames would solve which of these

Comment: @FereshTeh Ok, that is something you should [edit] into the question.

Comment: If you're going to downvote, add a reason why. Don't be passive-aggressive. It's bad for the community. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexReynolds It is not required to disclose, but I think that the downvote button already explain this: "does not show research effort, it is unclear or not useful". Asking for an explanation from downvoters is also passive-aggressive...

Comment: @FereshTeh I used `col_name` as a name for the new column that will be generated by the function `rownames_to_column`. I should have used `'col_name'` (with quotes), sorry about that!

Comment: @AlexReynolds I kinda agree with llrs. In addition to not showing research effort, OP has a habit of editing her posts extensively and changing the entire premise once she receives a response, and such behavior needs to be discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the definition of `t`:

```
...
> t <- sapply(seq(ncol(t(biomarker))), function(x) f(t(biomarker)[,x], t(immune)[,x]))
```

Set the column names to the gene names from one or the other of your conditions:

```
> colnames(t) <- rownames(immune)
```

Set the cutoff:

```
> cutoff <- 0.05
```

Filter for rows which meet the p-value cutoff criterium, and get their column names (gene names):

```
> colnames(t)[which(unlist(lapply(t["pval",], function(x) x < cutoff)))]
[1] "ABCC6" 
...
```

Only one gene name is reported here, using your demo datasets. Adjust your cutoff and criterium logic, as needed. For example, I filter here for gene names where the p-value is *less* than the cutoff; however, from your question, you may be asking for the inverse, for whatever reason, so you could change `<` to `>=`.

Comment: I might suggest changing the variable name `t` to something else, as `t()` takes the transpose of the argument, if of matrix or data frame type. Using non-ambiguous variable names will make it easier for you to make changes or fix problems down the road.

Answer (score 2):

From your example we are comparing samples not genes, I think we need to run the test row wise, something like this:

```
pvalueGenes <- sapply(colnames(biomarker),
                      function(i) t.test(biomarker[i, ],
                                         immune[i, ], paired = TRUE)$p.value)

names(pvalueGenes)[ pvalueGenes < 0.05 ]
```

Comment: Thank you, I added output of what you suggested in my post

Comment: Sorry, I have 2 matched matrices with matched samples and genes I want to find genes with p-value < 0.05 between 2 matrices but I could not do that

Comment: @FereshTeh forget your function `f`, there is no need, just run the commands in my answer. And check what you see in `pvalueGenes` object.

Comment: Thank you but your code itself giving error please have a look at error I added to my post

Comment: @FereshTeh The reason for error is statistics, read about it [more here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/112972/6454). Suggestion, when you get an error try to use the search, 99% of the time the error has been searched before and you will find the solution/explanation.

Comment: @zx8754, although `names(x)[ x < 0.05 ]` works, would it not be better to use `names(x[ x < 0.05 ])`, so each layer is a logical unit?

Comment: @RamRS Not sure what you mean by "logical unit". Yes both approaches work, but your version is about 1.14 times slower, tested on 100K vector.

Comment: Ah, I see. Never mind, then. By logical unit, I meant that `x`, `x[x<0.05]` and `names(obj)` are all self-contained, whereas `names(x)[boolean_vector]` is written in a way that the subsetting depends on understanding the statement as a whole.